# How to replace <p> tag with a comma symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden field with a value `<p>Copy 1</p><p>Copy 2</p><p>Copy 3</p><p>Copy 4</p>`. I would like to replace the `</p>` tags with a comma symbol and remove the `<p>` tags so that the final output will be `Copy 1,Copy 2,Copy 3,Copy 4`. I tried using the JavaScript `replace('<p>','')` function, but I couldn't remove it.

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: Maybe your <p> are actually &lt;p&gt;?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the map function, and then join the array with ', '.

```
$.map(
    $('<p>Copy 1</p><p>Copy 2</p><p>Copy 3</p><p>Copy 4</p>'), 
    function(val, i) { 
       return val.innerHTML; 
    }).join(', ');
```

Comment: Probably `$(val).text()` rather than `val.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

If you *need* to do it with .replace, you can do it like this (note that this does not rely on jQuery):

```
var stringToTest = "<p>Copy 1</p><p>Copy 2</p><p>Copy 3</p><p>Copy 4</p>";

stringToTest = stringToTest.replace(/<p>/g, "").replace(/<\/p>/g,",");

stringToTest = stringToTest.substr(0, stringToTest.length - 1);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vTpV2/

Comment: An easier way (in my opinion) to remove the final character in a string is to use `.slice(0, -1);`

Answer (score 1):

> *".I tried using the javascript `replace('<p>','')` function."*

If you want to do a global replace on a string you have to pass a regular expression with the global flag as the first argument. So:

```
var val = $("#idOfYourElementHere").val();

val = val.replace(/<\/p><p>/g, ', ')    // first swap <p></p> for commas
         .replace(/<\/?p>/g, '');       // then swap the leftover <p> and </p>
                                        // for empty strings (i.e., remove them)
```

Comment: Why would you recommend replacing HTML with regular expressions? Especially when the OP has something as powerful as jQuery at his disposal?

Comment: @Tomalak - Well firstly because the OP tried to use `.replace()`, so I was indicating a way to get that to work. Secondly because this is a really simple replacement so I don't think there's any need to make it more complicated by operating on it as html. Thirdly I don't actually object to doing it as in Blazes's answer, but I saw that answer before I posted mine and didn't want to double up (I know my answer is similar to Chris's, but he only beat me by ten seconds so I didn't see his answer until after I'd posted, and since I'd done it slightly differently I left it).

Comment: That's my point. The context the OP gave does not support the assumption that it's really "just a simple replacement". In any case it's fundamentally wrong to use `.replace()` on HTML and "making it work anyway" does more harm than good. Properly parsing the snippet is the only correct solution.

Comment: @Tomalak - The only context given is that the string is in a hidden "field", which I took to be an input. We're not told why, so I provided a solution to the problem stated - how to replace the p tags with commas, which _is_ a simple string replacement. Parsing the html snippet may be the _best_ solution, but it is _not_ the only "correct" solution. Is the source format likely to change? We don't know, so if we're going to code for other possible formats why assume it will continue to be HTML when it could as easily end up as `"Copy 1", "Copy 2", ...` and need the quotation marks removed...

Comment: But is it sensible to recommend an inferior, practically incorrect solution (What about HTML entities? Nesting? Broken HTML? Your suggestion solves none of that.) on the sole assumption that the "problem stated" looks simple? Your code only works in the most favorable of circumstances. That's not a solid basis for any solution, even if I leave *don't-use-regex-on-HTML* zealotry aside for the moment. (Of course *don't-use-regex-on-HTML* is still always right and your solution is refutable on that argument alone.)

Comment: @Tomalak - What about HTML entities, nesting or broken html? The accepted solution is based on parsing the html but doesn't solve those problems either. I'm not criticising that answer: we don't know what the OP would want if there was, e.g., nesting (keep inner tags? Just keep text?). If it was my code I wouldn't be putting html in a hidden input in the first place only to convert it to a plain string (again, I've taken "field" to mean "input"). "Don't use regex to parse HTML" I agree with. "Never, ever use regex for any kind of operation on HTML" I do not agree with.

Comment: I agree about not putting HTML in a hidden input field. Makes no sense at all and whatever the OP is trying to do it should probably be done differently. — I'm only arguing because I think it's a strategic error to recommend regex to newbies asking about HTML. It teaches them to try the wrongest of approaches first. This is completely independent of "…but it works in this case". — BTW, *"Don't use regex to parse HTML"* is equal to *"Never, ever use regex for any kind of operation on HTML"*. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var _sHFVal = _sHFVal.split('<p>').join("").split('</p>').join(',');
_sHFVal = _sHFVal.substring(-1, _sHFVal.length-1);
```